# In-App Purchases stuck in "Missing Metadata" state

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, metadata

I am trying to set up in-app purchases but I don't know how to get rid of the "Missing Metadata" shown below.

The only yellow dot I see from the page is the "Localizations" section, but I completed the "Display Name" and "Description".

I don't know what else I can do or what I am doing wrong.

[image: Missing Metadata (yellow dot)]

---

[image: Missing Metadata (yellow dot)]

Comment: Are you sure you have entered an completed the rest of the form for your app?

Comment: Have you added a screenshot?

Comment: Please check if you have added screenshot

Comment: Screenshot and the description field in localization. I think it's a terrible user experience for Apple not put a * mark next to all the necessary fields.

Comment: I was also having same issue, the screenshot and other fields in form are mandatory.

Comment: Add at-least one localization in subscription group

Comment: Make sure you have add Localization and a review screenshot of 1200x800

Comment: from where i can get the screen shot?

Comment: @EvenCheng Have you tried uploading a screenshot? When I did freelance websites 10 years ago for a few hundred dollars I wrote my own function to resize uploaded images. Yet apple can't do it, they send you to a page where you have to manually resize your image before uploading it.

Answer (score 193):

Add any type of screenshot of the app here. Then Save and submit. It should work.

Update : You may add a description as well.
[image]

Comment: Kept getting "Invalid size", 1334x750 ended up working for me.

Comment: Would be nice if Apple were a little more specific with their error messages.

Comment: This will not longer work. I had two apps where I did the above and had been approved several times. My most recent submissions were rejected because the reviewer wanted a screen shot of the app. Your reviewer may or may not check as the review process seems to be inconsistent at times..

Comment: In my case, I only had to provide a screenshot for the App Review team: "Review Information". It'd be useful if an * was put next to the required items..

Comment: 1242 x 2688 worked for me. I think its more trial and error at this point.

Comment: In my case only resized to 640 x 920 work, as says documentation https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/dev84b80958f

Comment: I was confused, because the yellow-dot next to my Localizations is basically identical to the yellow dot next to "Missing Metadata". And the Promotion screenshot is optional. However, the Review screenshot is mandatory. After adding the appropriately sized review screenshot -it was ready to submit

Comment: And like me if anyone is looking for a dummy image here https://dummyimage.com/1024x768/b33bb3/0011ff.png&text=Hello

Comment: also **Review Notes** is a required field now, just adding screenshot without description doesn't work

Comment: @user3690202 would be nice if they automatically resized the image.

Answer (score 53):

I had the same issue with a renewable subscription.  Near the top of iTunes page, just below your image that says "Missing Metadata," I saw this:

[image: Before you can submit.... Add localizations]

I clicked on "Add Localizations" which took me to the group.  There is a broad frame instructing you to click somewhere else.  Click on the little blue circled plus to the right of "Localizations."

After selecting the language I filled in "Subscription Group Display Name" and saved.  The IAP status immediately changed to "Ready to Submit."

Comment: That was my problem too.

Comment: This was the problem in my case. 

Comment: Perfect answer bro.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me.  Is it me, or is App Store Connect the most complex, unhelpful, unintuitive portal that has ever existed!  Now I have to figure out how I submit the in app purchase for approval.  A button to do it, no, that would be too simple.  there will be some unnecessarily complex little icon, hidden somewhere to find.  Grrrr!

Comment: This was my problem as well. However, I never saw the "Add Localizations" button for the subscription group; somehow a prompt for adding the subscription group localization just appeared for an unknown reason after I had added a couple of more subscription products.

Answer (score 42):

Although the UI doesn't indicate it, a screenshot is **required** to submit your IAP for approval.

> A screenshot of the product as it appears on the device. This
>   screenshot is used for **Apple’s review only** and is not displayed on
>   the App Store.

Screenshots requirements are outlined below:

- iOS requires at least 640 x 920 pixels.
- tvOS requires 1920 x1080 pixels.
- macOS requires 1280 x 800 pixels.

Source: https://help.apple.com/itunes-connect/developer/#/dev84b80958f

The screenshot requirements are also inaccurate, for example a screenshot taken on a iPhone 11 is not accepted even though it clearly meets the stated requirements. iPhone SE 2 screenshots are accepted.

Comment: Even when an image meets these requirements, it still displays the error. For me only 1024 x 768 worked.

Comment: The size for iOS has changed to 2208x1242

Comment: screenshots from the iOS simulator are most likely to be accepted, seems to be a ratio story more than min resolution. Simulated iPhone 8 plus worked for me... as always negative kudos for the doc from Apple...

Comment: Incredibly lazy UI/UX design by Apple here. It does not state ANYWHERE that this screenshot is MANDATORY. Just adding a * to each field would be a massive improvement..

Comment: @Piou f*ck documentation. It would be incredibly easy to automatically resize the image on their side. But instead they let the lives of 100 of thousands poor chums like me rot.

Answer (score 17):

Any 1024x768 png image file added to the screenshot in Review Information has solved the issue

Comment: Thanks. Why Apples documentation and UX is so useless?

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me, had to resize the image.

Comment: Change your answer to 

iOS requires at least 640 x 920 pixels.

tvOS requires 1920 x1080 pixels.

macOS requires 1280 x 800 pixels.

Comment: I did not believe it help. But it helps.

Answer (score 8):

For me, It was the subscription group name I missed. Add at-least one localization.

[image]

Comment: fixed for me thanks!

Answer (score 7):

For iOS in-app purchase, you need an image size of at least 640 x 920 pixels.

> iOS requires at least 640 x 920 pixels.
>
> tvOS requires 1920 x1080 pixels.
>
> macOS requires 1280 x 800 pixels.

These are the [Apple guidelines](https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/dev84b80958f).

Comment: Note: I had to save my images as jpgs to be accepted.

Answer (score 5):

Add **a screenshot** to your review part **at the bottom** and it will change to **ready to submit**.

Answer (score 4):

In my case the issue was information missing under the "Group Reference Name". Would be nice if error message was more specific. [image]

Comment: This helped me. My issue was missing localization of subscription group

Answer (score 3):

Use Opera browser, it solved my problem by uploading below:
iOS requires at least 640 x 920 pixels for Review Screenshot

Answer (score 3):

Same issue here. Solved uploading an image generated with the simulator:

- Run the app in the simulator, go to the VC with the In App Purchase information.
- Cmd + S -> This creates a screenshot of the simulator with the device resolution.
- Find the screenshot just created in the desktop.
- Drag & drop it to the AppStoreConnect/YourApp/Features/In-App Purchases/Review Information/Screenshot.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Apple actually has a page for explaining the details of each error message. You can refer to the official documentation - [In-app purchase statuses](https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/dev840c56fb6) here.

Answer (score 2):

In my case the problem was that the price wasn't specified; I didn't actually have sufficient permissions to set a price (my role was 'Developer') so the section didn't appear and I didn't notice it was missing.

Answer (score 2):

[image]The one thing that was keeping it in 'MISSING METADATA' was 'DESCRIPTION' was empty.

As soon as I added to the 'DESCRIPTION' it changed to 'READY TO SUBMIT'.

Answer (score 2):

I added a screenshot from iPhone 11 Pro Max (simulator) for review and it works!

Answer (score 1):

Near the top left under a few other things there is a "Duration" drop down that asks you how long you want your subscription to be (assuming it is a subscription you are doing).

I think this is what I missed the first time, or possibly the screenshot for the testing at the bottom.

Swapped to "Ready to Submit" right when I saved everything this time, now I just need to upload a new build!  Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

In may case, the metadata for the In App Purchase *itself* (e.g., screenshot, description, price) was OK. But I forgot to **include** the IAP in the app release's page "In-App Purchases" list:

[image]

Of course, I had to figure this out by myself because Apple's response template messages don't tell you Jack S*** about what is missing and how to fix it.

**Hope this helps someone.**

Comment: I don't have In-App Purchases under the app, is that only after enabling the entitlement?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately none of the answers here seem to explain why a seemingly valid screenshot taken on a device isn't working.... several years on the documentation still isn't any clearer either!

`iOS requires at least 640 x 920 pixels.`

**TRANSLATION:**
`640 x 920 pixels is just one of the accepted screenshot sizes`

From some trial and error, it would seem that the screenshot must be provided in **rendered pixels**, but only at the **highest** pixel density for that size group.

e.g.

- iPhone 4/4S etc = 320x480 @ 2x = **640x960**
- iPhone 5/SE etc = 320x568 @ 2x = **640x1136**
- iPhone 6/6S/7/8/SE2 = 375x667 @ 2x = **750x1334**
- iPhone 6+/6S+/7+/8+ = 414x736 @ 3x = **1242x2208**
- iPhone X/XS/11 Pro/12 mini/13 mini = 375x812 @ 3x = **1125x2436**
- iPhone XR/11/11 Pro Max = 414x896 @ 3x = **1242x2688**
- iPhone 12/12 Pro/13/13 Pro = 390x844 @ 3x = **1170x2532**
- iPhone 12 Pro Max/13 Pro Max = 428x926 @ 3x = **1284x2778**

(this explains why for example iPhone 11 screenshots rendered at the native 2x aren't working, despite being above the 640 x 920 limit at 828x1792)

It should also be noted that saving a screenshot using the iOS Simulator often saves the image at less than 100% scale, which is why your simulator screenshots aren't acceptable either!

Hopefully this answer should provide a future-proof solution until the documentation gets updated properly!

Answer (score 0):

**Add Screenshot from real device**

In my case, I added an iPhone 8 Screenshot from the simulator but It did not upload.
Then I added a screenshot from a real iPhone 8 device and working fine. ready to submit.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forgot to add localization to Subscription Group !!!!

Answer (score 0):

The "Missing Metadata" appears if there's any missing fields like localization,
add at least one localization with its details
or review information,
you have to upload a photo to the purchased product and this for review only as indicated from app store, for more info about uploaded photo specs check this https://developer.apple.com/help/app-store-connect/reference/screenshot-specifications

Answer (score 0):

When using the App Store Connect API to create subscriptions (I was creating quite a few), I found that is was necessary to create a price for every country even though my app was only available in two countries. When you create a subscription from the App Store Connect web page, it creates prices for every country whether you want it to or not (as far as I can tell). Creating a price for every country resolved my missing metadata problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to save the listing without setting up the 'Availability' of the item but it seems like this is key and has to be set. Once I set the 'Availability' the status changed to 'Ready to Submit'.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had setup of all the localizations, description and etc. However, I was missing the screenshot. As soon as I uploaded a screenshot, the status changed from "missing metadata" to "ready to submit".

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the screenshot was stuck on "Processing". I had to remove it and reupload it.